# android emulator/eclipse deletes application files on redeployment

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

My Application downloads a file from a server and stores it in:
`/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.test/files`. (the /mnt/sdcard is derived from `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` )

Everytime I redeploy the Application from eclipse(run menu) to the emulator it deletes the file.
The Checkbox 'target/wipe user data' in the run configuration is unchecked.
I close all the `BufferedOutputStreams` properly so I don't think it is my application itself.
Am I using the right directory for persistent data storage? (my Files are around 70-100M)

Any hints?

Comment: com.test your app package name right?  maybe different SDcard location..are the files marked readable for everyone or just the app?

Answer (score 1):

From the [getExternalStorageDirectory's doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29xternalStoragePublicDirectory(String).):

> Applications should not directly use
>   this top-level directory, in order to
>   avoid polluting the user's root
>   namespace. Any files that are private
>   to the application should be placed in
>   a directory returned by
>   Context.getExternalFilesDir, which the
>   system will take care of deleting if
>   the application is uninstalled. Other
>   shared files should be placed in one
>   of the directories returned by
>   getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String).

Your `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.test/files` should be in your `Context.getExternalFilesDir()` and it gets deleted when the app is uninstalled.